# rack-rewrite remove slashes if not pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, url-rewriting, rack

I'm using [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) in my app to remove trailing slashes if found, but I only want that if not on a certain route.

I've used something like:

```
use Rack::Rewrite do
  r301 %r{^(?!testroute)(.+)/$}, '$1'
end
```

To achieve what I need (e.g. all routes but `/testroute/` should have any trailing slashes removed). The issue is that even if it hits that specific route, it does not ignore it and it remove the trailing slashes. Is my regex wrong, or is there something that I am not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead.

```
r301 %r{^(?!.*testroute)(.+)/$}, '$1'
```

Comment: Can I enforce a slash on the same rule ?

Comment: Instead of remove trailing slash append if it's not there, on this route

Comment: You could always replace it and add it back. `'$1/'`

Comment: But can I use two rules, one that strips slashes (only if not login) and one that adds slashes if login