# url rewrite pattern generates to many redirects

Tags: ruby, regex, url-rewriting, rack

I have been struggling with the same issue for a while now and I could not find an good answer yet. I'm using [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) to add some url rewrite rules to my app's middleware stack.

I have the following rule:

```
r301 %r{^/([^(docs|help|legal|login|account|apps)])(.+)/$}, '$1'
```

Which is not working properly or as I would expect it. I have tried one of my previous question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324996/rack-rewrite-remove-slashes-if-not-pattern), but neither that works, it actually generates an event more weird behaviour (it redirects to an url without the domain name, just to the path).

What I am trying to do is:

- if user requests `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/random-path/` I need the rewrite rule to strip the slash, thus the examples would become `http://example.com` respectively `http://example.com/random-path`;
- if the requested paths matches any of the paths in the list `docs|help|legal|login|account|apps`, do not strip the slash at the end of the path if exists, but add a slash if it's not there

I tried with two rules, one that ignores the listed paths above and strips slashes and one that adds the slash if it hits something from the list and the slash after the path is not there:

```
r301 %r{^/([^(docs|help|legal|login|account|apps)])(.+)/$}, '/$1'
r301 %r{^/([(docs|help|legal|login|account|apps)])(.+)/$}, '/$1/'
```

How could I write a rule that would do that, or two rules, because what I tried it did not work?

Comment: `[]` is a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and does not do what (I assume) you think it does.

Comment: I see, but doesn't `[^...]` negate the character set? Or actually it only works for `[^a-z]` or something similar?

Comment: yes, you should read the linked article but basically `[ab]` matches a or b `[^ab]` matches any character that is not a or b but both only match a *single* character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like so:

```
r301 %r{^/((?!docs|help|legal|login|account|apps).+)/$}, '/$1'
r301 %r{^/((?=docs|help|legal|login|account|apps).+[^/])$}, '/$1/'
```

[example 1](http://regex101.com/r/pS2sM3)

[example 2](http://regex101.com/r/wS5rX3)

and [some documentation on lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

EDIT: stray parentheses.

Comment: this does not work and you have an extra parenthesis on each line

Comment: It seems like if I try something like `http://example.dev/docs/` it hits a redirect loop and the browser crashes ...

Comment: @rolandjitsu good point, there shouldn't be a forward slash on the end of that. fixed now.

Comment: Now the url becomes `http://example.dev/docs//////////////////////` ... perhaps a check for existing ending slash is needed?

Comment: Have you got the right regex? have a look at the example 1 and example 2 to see what's happening.

Comment: I am using the latest edit and now there are less slashes at the end `http://example.dev/docs///////`

Comment: actually I think it works, it might be my browser appending those slashes now ... I tried a different path and it seems like the behaviour is what I would expect ... I wonder why it behaves so strange on the path that I have tried the first time `/docs`